# Styles and themes on values, values-v11 and values-v14 folders

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I am currently working on my app to base its design on the Holo theme. Globally what I want to do is working but I am a little confused about the way that are working the folders `values`, `values-v11` and `values-v14`.

So I know that:

- `values` is targeting the API inferior to 11
- `values-v11` is targeting the API between 11 and 13
- `values-v14` is targeting the API superior to 13

At first I thought I had to specify for every folder all the styles needed for the app but then I realized a kind of inheritance system was in place.

My problem is that I am really confused and don't understand clearly how is working this inheritance between these 3 folders.

I did the following test in order to see the behavior on my phone (running on Android 4.0, so the folder `values-v14` should be the one loaded):

In `values` I have a style to set in blue the text color:

```
<style name="TextMedium" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Blue</item>
```

In `values-v11` I have a style to set in white the text color:

```
<style name="TextMedium" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
```

In `values-v14` I have a style to set in red the text color:

```
<style name="TextMedium" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Red</item>
```

For the first case above (every folder with a different color), the color loaded on my text is red, meaning the `values-v14` folder gets the priority.

Then if I comment out the red style from the `values-v14` folder, the text becomes white. Does that mean that the system will take the style in the `values-v11` folder even if the device is targeting the `values-v14` folder? I thought it would maybe use the `values` folder by default but not `values-v11`.

More generally, my question is, are these 3 folders working as parent and child? 
Meaning that:

- If the device is running on a API version > 13, the system will load `values-v14` then `values-v11` and finally `values`.
- If the device is running on a API between 11 and 13, the system will load `values-v11` and then `values`.
- If the device is running on a API version < 11, the system will load only `values`.

If it is indeed the way it is working, does it make sense then to setup the maximum of styles in the parent folder `values` and add only specific ones in v11 or v14?

Sorry for the long question, I hope it is clear, this themes/styles system is only described briefly in the Android guide and it is difficult to find information on how it works...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `values-v14` targets API >= 14, `values-v11` targets API between(including) 11 and 13 **if** `values-v14` is present **otherwise** it will match every version starting with 11 and above.

`values` is the default folder and it will be the last to be matched, covering other API levels not covered by another `values-xx` folder.

Comment: Thanks Luksprog. Based on that mechanism, it means that it is better to only setup in v11 and v14 styles that cannot be used by lower versions? (and so to keep the simple styles like the one I posted in `values`?)

Comment: That's the idea, use version indicators when using attributes added from that version on. For example, Honeycomb introduced the `activatedBackgroundIndicator` attribute for a `ListView`. As this is not present below `11` the `values` folder will not use this but you could include a `values-v11` folder to take advantage of the attribute in the app for versions that do have it. But you need to have the other styles present if you have different folders.

Comment: Thanks! You answered my doubts, I have now a clear idea on how to use it properly.

Comment: Luksprog, you should add your comment as an official answer - otherwise this question will keep showing up in the Unanswered bucket.

Comment: @Luksprog, post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> More generally, my question is, are these 3 folders working as parent
>   and child?

Those folders work with a "most specific" matching system meaning it will match the closest(lower) API level `values` folder:

- `values-v14` targets APIs >= `14`(it will not be selected at all for versions below `14`)
- `values-v11` targets APIs between(and including) `11` and `13` if `values-v14` is present **otherwise** it will match every version starting with `11` and above((it will not be selected at all for versions below `11`))
- `values` is the default folder and it will be the last to be matched, covering other APIs levels not covered by another `values-xx` folder. You should always(as with all resources folders) have this folder in your app

> If it is indeed the way it is working, does it make sense then to
>   setup the maximum of styles in the parent folder values and add only
>   specific ones in v11 or v14?

Yes, this is how the Android project template is built(when you use `Create new project...`), it actually tells you to use the `values-xx` folders for customization(different look, use of newer styles, attributes):

```
 <!-- in the styles.xml from the v-14 values folder: -->
 <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
```

Comment: Hey, I have 1 doubt. Let's say that I have a style that is completely different in values, but share a lot of items in values-v11 and values-v14. So, is it a good idea to create a common theme in values-v11 folder? And then inherit that theme in values-v14 and add extra items?