# Android: values-v14 style.xml applies on device with API level 18

Tags: android

I'm sure I'm misunderstanding something fundamental, but why does the `styles.xml` from the folder `values-v14` apply on a device running Jelly Bean 4.3 (API level 18)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> values-v14 targets API >= 14, values-v11 targets API
>   between(including) 11 and 13 if values-v14 is present otherwise it
>   will match every version starting with 11 and above. values is the
>   default folder and it will be the last to be matched, covering other
>   API levels not covered by another values-xx folder.

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624317/styles-and-themes-on-values-values-v11-and-values-v14-folders) out