# Create theme as per android version

Tags: android, themes, android-manifest

Hi I am having an old app created on version 2.2.3.
I am modifying the app for 4.0 and above version handsets.
can someone tell me if I can use selective theme
like for 2.2 devices dark black theme
For 3.0 and above the holo 
Can i use version specific themes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a different values folder with following name:

values-v17

and put a copy of style.xml init

in this `style.xml` you can overrite styles set in default values folder and for the devices with API-17 this style will be applied

If you have a folder for values-v11 all the devices with API level 11 and more will refer to files from this folder.

Comment: do i need to make this for all the version from v11
and in manifest file, style attribute what should I specify

Comment: you can checkout this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624317/styles-and-themes-on-values-values-v11-and-values-v14-folders