# Style in values-v11 and values-v14

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I wonder what would happen if i write some code in the file style.xml in the folder values-v14 and when this is executed in a device than not use this api 14, would happen in that case ?

I am new in this language of android..

Thank for your time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth indicating that i.e. `values-v14` will be used for

1. `API 14` and higher, unless there's another folder that got higher
   version i.e. on `API 14` and higher, content of `values-v14` will be
   used.
2. it will not be selected at all for versions below `API 14`

For more info you may see at 
[Styles and themes on values, values-v11 and values-v14 folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624317/styles-and-themes-on-values-values-v11-and-values-v14-folders)

Comment: just, i create an style of ActionBar in the folder values-v14 because in the folder values i can't to create this style and for this reason y ask this question, because i don't know what happend in the device that don't soppurt api 14...

Comment: maybe i am confuse with api 14 and api 11.. i don't understand the concept of then in a device android...