# Align Bottom of ColapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: java, android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, nestedscrollview

I have Activity where I have a CollapsingTableLayout and I'd to display in the bottom of the screen an Editext but I have some problems

[image]

When I scroll to bottom, all text not displayed

[image]

And when I clic in Editext in the bottom, Toolbar is not displayed

[image]

I follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980503/android-nestedscrollview-bottom-two-button-attached) to do this

Here is my Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".DetailActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:behavior_overlapTop="64dp">
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    app:cardElevation="6dp"
                    android:id="@+id/detail_info"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/detail_title"
                            android:text="Title"
                            android:textSize="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/detail_description"
                            android:text="Description"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/detail_title"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/detail_comment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="6"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/detail_add_comment"
            android:text="add"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_send"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for help