# Show CollapsingToolbarLayout Title ONLY when collapsed doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have the standard implementation of AppBarLayout with CollapsingToolbarLayout in my Activity.

I follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662416/show-collapsingtoolbarlayout-title-only-when-collapsed) to show the CollapsingToolbarLayout title only when collapsed:

```
mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        boolean mIsShow = false;

        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            float percentage = ((float) Math.abs(verticalOffset) / appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange());

            if (!mIsShow && percentage == 1) {
                mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(mToolbarTitleText);
                mIsShow = true;
                LogUtils.LOGD("XXXX", "SHOW =" + mToolbarTitleText);

            } else if (mIsShow && percentage != 1) {
                mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(" ");
                mIsShow = false;
                LogUtils.LOGD("XXXX", "HIDE");
            }
        }
    });
```

This works very well, except when I set, in developer options on mobile, **Don't keep activity**: when I come back in this Activity, the CollapsingToolbarLayout title is hidden all the time. I can't understand why because the logs are correctly show.